# JavaScript: Optimizing against Redundancy (Loop + Switch + Key/Value)

Tags: javascript, loops, optimization, switch-statement

Is there a better way to do this?

I have a function `element.getFormData` that builds a parameterized string if called with any element in a form, like a submit button. It's just a simple loop to gather all the input values in the form. What I like about it, is that it also hard returns if it detects a file upload, which you have to do anyway, so that the appropriate alternative method can handle that case. What I don't like about it is the redundancy in the loop. I will show you what I mean.

```
element.getFormData     = 
function(_R)
{   var vars="";var form=this,i=0,n,o,en=encodeURIComponent;

    while(form){if('FORM'===form.tagName)break;form=form.parentNode}
        form=form.getElementsByTagName('*');

    while(n=form[i++])
    {   switch((n.type||'').toLowerCase())
        {   case'file':
                if(_R)
                    return false;
            case'radio':
            case'checkbox':
                if(n.checked)
                    vars+=  "&" +   en(n.name||n.id)
                        +   "=" +   en(n.value);
            break;
            break;
            case'select-multiple':
                for(var k=0;o=n.options[k++];)
                    if(o.selected)
                        vars+=  "&"     +   en(n.name||n.id)
                            +   "="     +   en(o.value||o.text);
            break;
            default:
                switch(n.tagName)
                {   case'INPUT':
                    case'TEXTAREA':
                        vars+=  "&" +   en(n.name||n.id)
                            +   "=" +   en(n.value);
                    break;
                    break;
                    case'SELECT':
                        vars+=  "&" +   en(n.name||n.id)
                            +   "=" +   en((o=n.options[n.selectedIndex]).value||o.text);
                }
        }
    }
    return vars
};
```

So, it's basically doing the same thing for each input type, just appending a key value pair as a string. That gives me the feeling it should be consolidated. We can even see at least the key part, `vars+=   "&" +   en(n.name||n.id)`, is exactly the same for each one.

It seems a case like this is a limitation of the language: where we are using a switch inside of a loop for a shared instruction of logic, but each case varies specifically enough to cause redundancy. Sometimes, we just vary slightly, where sometimes, we have other distinguishing factors, and sometimes we have to step that logic inside of another loop. At any rate, however, it's essentially the same logic, and should be simplified, either in the methodology and/or in the language's constructs.

So, before I go any further, does anybody have a better method?

Because, now, I have another function `element.getFormDataObject` because, while that function returned all my data, it was in a string, but what if I need to modify that data? So this function does basically the exact same thing, but returns an object. It didn't make sense to me to *always* return an object and then translate it into a string because that would be unnecessary overhead when you just need a string. I traded functional overhead for asset overhead. (This one can't do the hard return if it detects a file upload because it assumes you need the data if you called it.)

```
element.getFormDataObject   = 
function( )
{   var data={};var form=this,i=0,n,o;

    while(form=form.parentNode){if('FORM'===form.tagName)break}
        form=form.getElementsByTagName('*');

    while(n=form[i++])
    {   switch((n.type||'').toLowerCase())
        {   case 'radio':
            case 'checkbox':
                if(n.checked)
                    data[n.name||n.id]=n.value;
            break;
            break;
            case 'select-multiple':
                for(var k=0;o=n.options[k++];)
                    if(o.selected)
                        (data[n.name||n.id]=data[n.name||n.id]||[]).push(o.value||o.text);
            break;
            default:
                switch(n.tagName)
                {   case'INPUT':
                    case'TEXTAREA':
                        data[n.name||n.id]=n.value;
                    break;
                    break;
                    case'SELECT':
                        data[n.name||n.id]=(o=n.options[n.selectedIndex]).value||o.text
                }
        }
    }
    return data
};
```

Again, this is a case of redundancy. It's like we need to be able to specify the template for each case and datatype and just issue one simple logic instruction inside one loop.

Additionally, I still actually have to have `element.toFormData` to translate the object into the string.

```
element.toFormData      = 
function( )
{   var text="",en=encodeURIComponent;
    for(var k in this)
    {   if(typeof this[k]==='string')
            text+=  "&" +   en(k)
                +   "=" +   en(this[k])
        else
            for(var i in this[k])
                text+=  "&" +   en(k)+"["+i+"]"
                    +   "=" +   en(this[k][i])
    }
    return text
};
```

So, we have a lot of redundant logic all throughout the implementation.

Would really appreciate any thoughts!!!

Comment: Why do you have multiple `break;` statements in a row?

Comment: Good place to start mitigating redundancy. ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way of shrinking duplicate code in JS is through the creation of functions.
A second is through functional techniques, which limit the amount of loop-management boilerplate you need.

In the example below, you'll see that the size of the two functions I've created (`getFormData` and `buildFormEncodedString`) are both rather small.
Of course, they're also delegating out to a number of named-helpers, typically 1-5 lines long, and the total file-size has increased.

Many of those helpers, themselves can be removed, using higher-order functions

```
// instead of
function isSelected (option) { return option.selected; }
function isChecked (input) { return input.checked; }
function isDisabled (input) { return input.disabled; }

inputs.filter(isChecked).filter(isDisabled);


// higher-order function
function is (trait) {
  return function (obj) { return obj[trait]; };
}
// implementation of "not" should be straightforward, once "is" is understood
inputs.filter(not(is("disabled"))).filter(is("checked"));
```

Even switching to ES6-syntax, and using only destructuring and arrow-lambdas could add clarity and cut down on excess reading:

```
// instead of
function appendKeyValueToObject (object, pair) {
  var key = pair[0];
  var value = pair[1];
  object[key] = value;
  return object;
}

// ES6 allows
function appendKeyValueToObject (object, [key, value]) {
  object[key] = value;
  return object;
}

// instead of
inputs
.filter(function (input) {
  return input.type !== "file";
})
.map(function (input) {
  return [input.name, input.value];
});

// ES6 allows
inputs.filter(input => input.type !== "file").map(input => [input.name, input.value]);
```

In any case, a lot of work is now being done, with fewer moving parts to worry about.

You mentioned that you didn't want to incur "overhead" by having a function parse the form, and another function transform the data...
...but the overhead you're talking about (from a performance standpoint) is super-minimal (compared to, say, running an OpenGL game at 60fps, using canvas).
It also comes with the added bonus of being able to pop that data into any transform you'd like, for any reason (multipart form upload, JSON upload, et cetera).
By forcing your function to do multiple things (grab the element, find the nearest form ancestor, find all elements whether they are for input or layout, pull out all key/value pairs, push them into strings), you have completely precluded the ability to write the reusable functions which you wanted in the first place.

Have a look at the included example, and hopefully, the benefits of this level of separation, and more set-based techniques will become apparent.

```js
initializePageListeners();

function initializePageListeners () {
  var trigger = query("#trigger-collection");
  var jsonArea = query("#print-data");
  var uriArea = query("#print-uri");

  trigger.onclick = function () {
    var form = query("#PersonForm");
    var data = getFormData(form);
    jsonArea.value = JSON.stringify(data);
    uriArea.value = buildFormEncodedString(data);
  };
}


function getFormData (form, keepFiles) {
  var inputs = queryAll("input", form);
  var scalarInputs = inputs.filter(isInputActive).filter(isNotFile);
  var textareas = queryAll("textarea", form);
  var selects = queryAll("select", form);

  var inputValues = concat(scalarInputs, textareas).map(extractInputNameValuePair);
  var inputFiles = !keepFiles ? [] : inputs.filter(isFile).map(extractInputFiles);
  var selectValues = selects.map(extractNameValueSets);

  var formData = buildFormData([inputValues, inputFiles, selectValues]);
  return formData;
}

function buildFormData (inputs) {
  return inputs.reduce(concat, []).reduce(appendKeyValueToObject, {});
}

function buildFormEncodedString (data) {
  var encodedString = Object.keys(data)
    .map(function (key) { return [ key, data[key] ]; })
    .map(function (pair) {
      var key = pair[0];
      var value = pair[1];
      return Array.isArray(value) ? formEncodePairs(key, value) : formEncodePair(key, value);
    }).join("&");

  return encodedString;
}

function formEncodePair (key, value) {
  return [key, value].map(encodeURIComponent).join("=");
}

function formEncodePairs (key, values) {
  return values.map(function (value) { return formEncodePair(key, value); }).join("&");
}

function appendKeyValueToObject (obj, pair) {
  var key = pair[0];
  var value = pair[1];
  var keyExists = (key in obj);

  if (keyExists) {
    obj[key] = concat(obj[key], value);
  } else {
    obj[key] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}

function extractNameValueSets (select) {
  var multiple = select.type === "select-multiple";
  var name = select.name;
  var options = slice(select.options);
  var selectedOptions = options.filter(isSelected).map(function (option) { return option.value || option.text; });

  return [ name, multiple ? selectedOptions : selectedOptions[0] ];
}

function extractInputFiles (input) {
  var key = input.name || input.id;
  var files = input.files;
  return [key, files];
}

function extractInputNameValuePair (input) {
  var value = input.value;
  var key = input.name || input.id;
  return [key, value];
}

function isSelected (option) { return option.selected; }
function isFile (input) { return input.type === "file"; }
function isNotFile (input) { return !isFile(input); }
function isInputActive (input) {
  var canCheck = /radio|checkbox/i.test(input.type);
  return canCheck ? input.checked : true;
}

function query (selector, node) {
  var root = node || document;
  return root.querySelector(selector);
}

function queryAll (selector, node) {
  var root = node || document;
  return slice(root.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

function concat (a, b) {
  return [].concat(a).concat(b);
}

function slice (arrLike, start, end) {
  return [].slice.call(arrLike, start, end);
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

#print-data, #print-uri {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="PersonForm">
  <fieldset >
    <legend >Name</legend>
    <label >first: <input name="firstName"></label>
    <label >last: <input name="lastName"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset >
    <legend >Gender</legend>
    <label >male: <input name="gender" value="male" type="radio"></label>
    <label >female: <input name="gender" value="female" type="radio"></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset >
    <legend >Language Experience</legend>
    <label >JavaScript
      <select name="jsExperience">
        <option>Amateur</option>
        <option selected>Apprentice</option>
        <option>Journeyman</option>
        <option>Expert</option>
        <option>Master</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label >CSS
      <select name="cssExperience">
        <option>Amateur</option>
        <option selected>Apprentice</option>
        <option>Journeyman</option>
        <option>Expert</option>
        <option>Master</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset >
    <legend >Paradigm Experience</legend>
    <label >Select all that apply
      <select name="paradigms" multiple>
        <option value="Object Oriented" selected>OO</option>
        <option selected>Functional</option>
        <option >Aspect Oriented</option>
        <option >Behaviour Driven Design</option>
      </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<button id="trigger-collection">get data</button>

<textarea id="print-data" style="display:block"></textarea>
<textarea id="print-uri" style="display:block"></textarea>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for exemplifying! That is a great start. I can see where certain functional techniques become highly pragmatic as project scope expands. With structural organization, this paradigm could scale effectively. (For example, classifying functions specific to forms, and then form data, etc.)

Comment: Where you have targeted function operation, or functional technique, I guess I'd call that variable functionality. In theory, variable functionality, sustainability (read: readability/maintainability) and scale go hand in hand. Ideally, so should optimality (read efficiency/effectiveness.) With enough accompanying variable functions, tuned for co-operation, the model could be exceptionally robust!

Comment: My only criticism, is the overhead. I would have to see benchmarking to prove that all the functionality, let alone datatypes, wouldn't incur too much, especially with scale. (However, that rate might improve.) Think of it this way: all we are doing is parsing an HTML form! When it comes to simple platforms, like the web-browser, in these cases, should we really be in the habit of instantiating several types and invoking chains of functions? I think there is still tremendous merit to this model, but maybe it needs more adaptation to the platform and case.

Comment: What do you think? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Structuring in a more object-oriented fashion, as a way of packaging functionality into services, is indeed a great technique to imploy.
lodash, as a library doesn't manage much private state at all, but it does have a "classical" interface. This model does become highly robust, as it's much like single-variable calculus `h(g(f(x))) === HGFx` 100% of the time. This makes it very easy to compose.

Comment: In fact, most of my projects use a helper library which I wrote to look similar: `var hgf = compose( h, g, f ); var hgfx = hgf(x);` with other helper functions atop of compose; it's highly-testable, as if you have something like: `var sumOfAgesAbove25 = compose( reduce(sum, 0), filter(gt(25)), map(pluck("age")) ); var total = sumOfAgesAbove25( people );` there is nary a character in that whole chain that isn't already behaving in a predefined manner. As to performance; you are parsing a form. Whether that takes 0.03ms or 0.5ms, or even 1ms, it's inconsequential.

Comment: The form is only parsed on an event, rather than recursively, or on a tight poll. I wouldn't recommend this type of code for doing pixel-manipulation inside of a bitmap; it's great structure, but when doing tens of millions of operations, trying to hit a 10ms or less timeframe, it's definitely sub-optimal, still. But that speaks to how little you need to worry about the overhead of parsing one form, once; we can play Unreal Tournament 3 in the browser, running on JS + OpenGL (rather than C++ and OpenGL). That says a lot about our current browser abilities.

Comment: Thanks, buddy! I'm very impressed with what you are saying. With OpenGL the browser gets very powerful and we can start using cool techniques, (so long as they are single-threaded,) but I'd say the XML/CSS/Evented JavaScript is broken in a lot of ways! (Consider Css 3d Transitions. Should be the biggest piece of cake for the GPU, but it's not even practical beyond simple animations.)

Comment: I think we'd have a lot to talk about. I'd be interested in your projects as well! I'd love to see these optimizations and paradigms converge into the language level. And I have some you  might find interesting too, for instance, a FS transpiler, that converts your filesystem to a javascript framework. james@htde.org Thanks for the help!!!